# How can I pass image url from parent component to child component via props [REACT.JS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Parent component and I'm importing the img to pass the url to child component

Parent Code:

```
import escopoIcon from '../../images/icons/escopo.png';

escopoServiceTab = {
    imgurl: {escopoIcon}
}

<!-- RENDER METHOD-->
<ServiceTab imgurl={this.escopoServiceTab.imgurl}/>
```

Child Code

```
<img src={props.imgurl} alt=""/>
```

In this way, I get an object... how can I get image URL and pass in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrap `escopoIcon` in `{}` inside `escopoServiceTab`, Remove the `{}` around it

```
escopoServiceTab = {
  imgurl: escopoIcon
}
```